# Android run code if connected to internet / wifi

Tags: java, android

I have an application that runs on boot up and that works great, my new problem is that my app requires an internet connection and my app gets booted up before there is an internet connect, thus I get a 404 error inside my app,

is there away to put this code below in a loop to if internet connection fails, them try the code again, like a try catch sorta thing. I am very new to java and would have no idea how to do this. Here is my code:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Loop Here to test if internet connection, if not try again

        WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        myWebView.loadUrl("http://example.com");

    }
```

I have also tried the following with a try and catch by now my application will not run altogether:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Socket socket = new Socket();
        InetSocketAddress address = new InetSocketAddress("www.google.com",80);
        try{
            socket.connect(address, 3000);
            WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
            myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
            myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            myWebView.loadUrl("http://example.com");
        } catch (Exception e){
            WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
            myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
            myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            myWebView.loadUrl("http://example.com");

        } finally {
            try {socket.close();}
            catch (Exception e){}
        }


    }
```

PLEASE HELP :(

And I have also been playing with this:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Thread t = new Thread();
        try{
            while(!isConnected(WifiExplorerActivity.this)){
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
        } catch (Exception e){

        }
        WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        myWebView.loadUrl("http://example.com");

    }
```

and adding this to my Manifest:

```
<activity android:name=".WifiExplorerActivity" >        
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: "put this code below in a loop to if internet connection fails, them try the code again" - you should NEVER use such loops, which only purpose is to run all the time while waiting for something to happen; read more about event-driven programming.

Answer (score 1):

You better try a BroadcastReceiver :

use : either use the whole class or just call the static methods

```
public class NetworkManager extends BroadcastReceiver {

    protected static final String   TAG                 = NetworkManager.class.getSimpleName(); // log
    protected Context               mContext;
    protected boolean               mNoConnectivity;
    protected String                mReason;
    protected boolean               mIsFailover;
    protected static boolean        mIsConnected        = false;
    protected static boolean        mIsConnectivityGood = true;

    public NetworkManager(Context context) {
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    public void registerReceivers() {
        mContext.registerReceiver(this, new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION));
    }

    public boolean isConnectingToInternet() {
        ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        if (connectivity != null) {
            NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
            if (info != null)
                for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++)
                    if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
                        return true;
                    }
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * @param context
     * @return
     */
    public static NetworkInfo getNetworkInfo(Context context) {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        return cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    }

    /**
     * @param context
     * @return
     */
    public static boolean isConnected(Context context) {
        NetworkInfo info = getNetworkInfo(context);
        return (info != null && info.isConnected());
    }

    /**
     * @param context
     * @return
     */
    public static boolean isConnectedWifi(Context context) {
        NetworkInfo info = getNetworkInfo(context);
        return (info != null && info.isConnected() && info.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
    }

    /**
     * @param context
     * @return
     */
    public static boolean isConnectedMobile(Context context) {
        NetworkInfo info = getNetworkInfo(context);
        return (info != null && info.isConnected() && info.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
    }

    /**
     * @param context
     * @return
     */
    public static boolean isConnectedFast(Context context) {
        NetworkInfo info = getNetworkInfo(context);
        return (info != null && info.isConnected() && isConnectionFast(info.getType(), info.getSubtype()));
    }

    protected static boolean isConnectionFast(int type, int subType) {
        if (type == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI) {
            return true;
        } else if (type == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE) {
            switch (subType) {
                case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_1xRTT:
                    return false; // ~ 50-100 kbps
                case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_CDMA:
                    return false; // ~ 14-64 kbps
                case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EDGE:
                    return false; // ~ 50-100 kbps
                case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EVDO_0:
                    return true; // ~ 400-1000 kbps
                case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EVDO_A:
                    return true; // ~ 600-1400 kbps
                case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_GPRS:
                    return false; // ~ 100 kbps
                case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSDPA:
                    return true; // ~ 2-14 Mbps
                case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSPA:
                    return true; // ~ 700-1700 kbps
                case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSUPA:
                    return true; // ~ 1-23 Mbps
                case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_UMTS:
                    return true; // ~ 400-7000 kbps
                case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_UNKNOWN:
                default:
                    return false;
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        mNoConnectivity = intent.getBooleanExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NO_CONNECTIVITY, false);
        mReason = intent.getStringExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_REASON);
        mIsFailover = intent.getBooleanExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_IS_FAILOVER, false);
        //
        if (mNoConnectivity) {
            mIsConnected = false;
        } else {
            if (isConnectedFast(mContext)) {
                mIsConnectivityGood = true;
            } else {
                mIsConnectivityGood = false;
            }
            mIsConnected = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have imported the BroadcastReceiver: `import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;` how would I rewrite my function to keep trying to connect until it does connect?

Comment: How about checking the connectivity with the method "isConnected" for example, and test the result "true/false". If it's true just do the request, if it is false notify the user and provide a way to retry

Answer (score 1):

Its Should work:

```
public class SMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
         WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
            wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);//make it enabled
       if(wifiManager.isWifiEnabled()){//if its enabled
//your code...
                 }
        }
    }
```

your should have on your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>//if you want to change it
```

Comment: I am not sure if I understand this...I am new to java, Would I want to create a new activity file for this code? and how would I get it call my onCreate function in my MainAcitivty?

Comment: Just for future visitors. You also need to declare `receiver` and `intent-filter` in your `Manifest`.

Answer (score 0):

This method works for me:

```
public static boolean isConnectivityOn(Context ctx) {
    boolean resCode = false;

    try {
        ConnectivityManager cm =
                (ConnectivityManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        resCode = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnectedOrConnecting();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        e.printStackTrace();

    }

    return resCode;
}
```

Taking care having

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

in the Manifest